# Is something like Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration available in Java?

Tags: java, configuration, environment-variables

I need to provide configuration for an application via environment variables and have come up with the below code. I come from a .NET Core background and am accustomed to using the tools in the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) namespace.

What tools are available in Java that are roughly analogous to those tools? Specifically, is there a way to populate a POJO class without having to explicitly read the environment variables?

```java
public class Settings {

    private String applicationKey;

    public Settings() {
        applicationKey = System.getenv("MYAPP_APPLICATION_KEY");
        uri = System.getenv("MYAPP_URI");
    }

    public String getApplicationKey() {
        return applicationKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: "is there a way to populate a PO class without having to explicitly read the environment variables?" - What is a PO class?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - PO = "Plain Old". That might not be a popular term... In .NET we use POCO (Plain Old Clr Object). I just updated the question to use POJO - is that term any more ubiquitous?

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, is there a way to populate a POJO class without having
> to explicitly read the environment variables?

There is nothing built into Java itself specifically to support what you are talking about but there are a lot of libraries that can help.  For example, your code could be changed to look like this if you were using Micronaut:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Settings {

    // This will automatically be initialized with the value
    // of the MYAPP_APPLICATION_KEY OS environment variable
    // if this instance is being managed by Micronaut...
    @Value("${myapp.application.key")
    String applicationKey;
    
    public String getApplicationKey() {
        return applicationKey;
    }
}
```